# Pasting from Excel with jQuery File Upload on page causes upload

Tags: excel, input, upload, copy-paste, jquery-file-upload

To boil it down, I have two inputs on the page. One is a text input, the other is a file input. If I copy and paste an Excel spreadsheet cell to the text input, it triggers a file upload to the file input. I'd like to allow copy-paste without triggering the file upload.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key here is to set the `pasteZone` to `null`

```
$("#fileupload").fileupload({
    pasteZone: null   //make it $(document) or specific container for enabling it
})
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#pastezone)

[Credit](http://idratherbewindsurfing.net/2013/01/21/pasting-from-ms-excel-into-jquery-file-uploader-plugin/)

Comment: I was having this issue, I thought it may be a pain to figure out, first result clear and concise thanks.

Comment: Awesome thanks ! This solved an pretty significant production issue for us. Our issue was occurring due to people copy pasting numerical values into a search field and that was triggering the upload, which was thoroughly confusing to say the least !